# How to ensure a set of Spring boot beans implementing an interface being first initalized before their container being initalized?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a set of beans both implementing an interface

```
@Componet
class BeanA implements interfaceA{
   public void process(){
   }
}

@Componet
class BeanB implements interfaceA{
   public void process(){
   }
}
```

I want to get all beans of interfaceA and apply their process methods sequentially, so I have a container to collect these beans.

```
@Componet
class Container{

List<interfaceA> container;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;    

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    container=applicationCOntext.getBeansOfType(interfaceA.class).values().stream().collect(Collections.list());
    for(obj:container){
        obj.process();
    }
}
```

So how can I ensure Container be initialized after all beans of interfaceA, so I can get all beans of interfaceA in init() method of Container?

Or put it another way, can applicationContext.getBeansOfType always get all beans of interfaceA? what if Container get initialzed first？

By the way, Container does not have to be a componet.

Comment: for your bean Container you can use the Order annotation with the value Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE

Comment: Don't inject the ApplicationContext in the container. Inject a List<InterfaceA> directly.

Comment: How am I supposed to Inject a List<InterfaceA> directly?@JB Nizet

Comment: You can use `@DependsOn(value = {"beanA", "beanB"})` on you `Container` class.

Comment: The same way you inject anything else: @Autowired List<InterfaceA> interfaceAs; (or preferrably, using constructor injection, the same way as you would inject anything else)

Comment: @Autowired List<InterfaceA> interfaceAs; can get all beans of interfaceA without writing other code? It sounds crazy.

Comment: Spring is indeed amzaing! I believe what you said now.@JB Nizet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject a list with all the components implementing `interfaceA`:

```
@Componet
class Container{

    @Autowired
    List<interfaceA> container;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        for(obj : container){
            obj.process();
        }
    }
}
```

In such a case you don't need to worry about components creation order, Spring is smart enough to make it right.

Components scanning/initialization is a two-step process. First, Spring collects all beans definitions and builds a dependency graph (without creating any beans). After that, it knows in what order the beans should be initialized. When you inject `interfaceA` beans as a list, Spring knows, that the `Container` instance depends on them and will initialize them first. It wouldn't be the case if you obtained the components manually from the `ApplicationContext` (the dependency would be hidden) and you would need @DependsOn annotations on the `interfaceA` components.

Comment: This solution is exactly what I want. My boss does not like @DependsOn. I guess I won't be fired tomorrow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would this solution also work in auto-configuration classes?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `@DependsOn(value = {"beanA", "beanB"})` on you `Container` class.
2. And Make your `Container` class implement `InitializingBean` interface and override the `afterPropertiesSet()` method.
3. And then move the logic that you've written in `init` method to `afterPropertiesSet()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mentioned points, you can use `SpringApplicationRunListener` interface for config `ConfigurableBootstrapContext` and `ConfigurableApplicationContext` in different application life cycles.